# Uniqueness of partial covariance/corrlation if OLS is not unique

Tags: correlation, linear-model, multicollinearity, partial-correlation, measure-theory

Let $X,Y,Z=(Z_1,...,Z_n)$ be random variables. Define the partial covariance between $X$ and $Y$ given $Z$ as: 
$$\rho_{X,Y \cdot Z} := cov(\hat{X}-X, \hat{Y}-Y)$$ where $\hat{X}$ and $ \hat{Y}$ are the best linear approximations of $X$ and $Y$ respectively by $(Z_1,...,Z_n)$.

I wonder what happens if the least Squares approximations are not unique. What I mean by that is that there are $\alpha_x,\alpha_y\beta_x, \beta_y\in \mathbb{R}^n, \alpha_x\neq\beta_x, \alpha_y\neq\beta_y$, such that $$E[(X-\beta_x^TZ)^t]=E[(X-\alpha_x^TZ)^t]= \underset{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}{\operatorname{argmin}}(E[(X-x^TZ)^2]) $$
and 
$$E[(Y-\beta_y^TZ)^t]=E[(Y-\alpha_y^TZ)^t]= \underset{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}{\operatorname{argmin}}(E[(Y-x^TZ)^2]) $$
In case there are unique solutions $\gamma_x, \gamma_y$ for the above minimisation problems, then one would simply set $\hat{X}:=\gamma_x^TZ$ and $\hat{Y}:=\gamma_y^TZ$ and the partial covariance would be unique. However if there are multiple solutions it is not obvious to me whether the partial covariance is uniquely defined, meaning e.g.  $cov(X-\alpha_x^TZ,Y-\alpha_y^TZ)= cov(X-\beta_x^TZ,Y-\beta_y^TZ)$. I suspect however that this should be the case, but I have no idea how to prove it or whether it is actually the case.

Comment: Could you supply an example of how the least squares approximations would not be "unique"?  That might clarify what you're trying to get at.

Comment: Thank you.  You seem to be conflating uniqueness of *parameter estimates* with uniqueness of *predicted values.*  The former might not be unique but the latter still will be.  This observation might set you on your way to proving the result you suspect is true.